# How to redirect to single post based on meta value from query string

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and not sure how to accomplish this.

I have a custom post type called `fs_parks`.  If I go to `fs_parks` it is a list of parks, as expected.  If I click on a custom post, I get to the singular post, as expected.

I have a map.  The map has a link like `www.example.com/fs_parks?osm_geometry=12345`. When clicked, I want to redirect to a singular post and show the park info basis the `meta_key=123456`.  I have a meta_key called `osm_geometry` that has a unique value for each park.

I understand I have to do something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'fs_park',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
              'key' => 'osm_geometry',
              'value' => get_query_var( 'osm_geometry' ),
              'compare' => '=',
      )
   )
);
$dbResult = new WP_Query($args);
```

But I do not know where to run it to ensure it is on a singular post.

Any help mych appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, use the `template_redirect` action hook. This hook is triggered before the template is loaded, allowing you to perform actions and redirects if some conditions are met.

Try this:

```
function redirect_to_park() {
    // Check if it is a single fs_park post
    if (is_singular('fs_park') && isset($_GET['osm_geometry'])) {
        $osm_geometry_value = sanitize_text_field($_GET['osm_geometry']);
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'fs_park',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'osm_geometry',
                    'value'   => $osm_geometry_value,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),
        );
        $dbResult = new WP_Query($args);
        // Check if there's a matching park
        if ($dbResult->have_posts()) {
            // Redirect to the first matching pak
            wp_redirect(get_permalink($dbResult->post->ID));
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_park');
```

This code checks for 2 conditions:

a: Is the current page a singular `fs_park` post? and,

b: Is the `osm_geometry` parameter set in the URL?

If the 2 conditions are met, it queries the database to find a matching park based on the `osm_geometry` value. If a matching park is found, it redirects to the singular post page for that park.

Add the code to your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Many thanks Obase.  I removed is_singular('fs_park') and it works.  My url looks like www.example.com/fs_park/?osm_geometry.  I think WP thinks is the archive page, right?  I guess I would test is_post_type_archive( 'fs_park' ) && isset($_GET['osm_geometry']), right?  Thanks again!